# QtでVboxLayoutを全画面にしたい

Tags: c++, qt

画面のサイズが変わっても中の画面のサイズを変えたいのと縦方向のレイアウトをframeで調整しようと思っています
frameをVBoxLayoutの中に配置したらVBoxLayoutのサイズに従ってframeのサイズも変わって
そこは良かったのですが
VBoxLayoutが親のフォームのサイズに合わせて調節されません
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
こんな感じなのですがQVboxLayoutをフォームに合わせて自動的にサイズ変更するようには出来ないでしょうか

VBoxLayoutを使わないでもflameだけで似たようなことができるならそちらでも良いです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

最も上位（親）にあたるウィジェットにVBoxLayoutを適用してみてください。

[image: ウィジェットレイアウト]